# How to change https to http for SSL error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl

My program was working successfuly until today afternoon.

Now, When i try to send a request to Binance API, it gives a SSL3 error like below;
Error:

```
write EPROTO 12280:error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:332
```

I'm working on Windows10 Visual Studio Code "Terminal" screen.
I don't have seperated server. How can i change https to http ?
Error screen is below;
[image]

My code body;

```
const Binance = require('node-binance-api');
const binance = new Binance().options({
    APIKEY: '***', 
    APISECRET: '***', 
    'recvWindow': 10000000
});
```

Basically sending a request to Binance API;

```
let minPrice = await binance.futuresCandles( "BTCUSDT", "1h", {limit:10} ).then(json => parseFloat(json[json.length-1][3])).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

**Edit:** I dont know what was the problem, but i reset modem and it worked.

Comment: Your backend is sending requests to some other API or some client is connecting to your API? Either way, there is not enough information here to provide any meaningful answer.

Comment: I am sending request to binance api, but binance API gives that error.

Comment: Well *How* are you sending your request?

Comment: @derpirscher i realised that when VPN opened, program doesn't give ssl error. Do you think why?